# Finding something in Mongoose DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Mongoose Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    genre: String, 
    authorName: {
        type: String,
        default: "none"
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Books", bookSchema)
```

And

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: {
        type: String,
        default: "none"
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Author", authorSchema)
```

I am storing Data in each model by doing something like this say (for books)

```
  let books = new book({
                    name: args.name, 
                    genre: args.genre,
                    authorName: args.authorName
   })
```

Here, I want to see if author doesn't exist, then it should create a new author itself for it.

**Question:** So, How can I search in my DB to see if the given author added via books exsist or not? and if not, then creating a new author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider utilizing the `pre` [save middleware hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for your model.

For example for books on `pre-save` if the author does not exist you would create one and add it to the current model. Something like this:

```
YourBookSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var bookModel = this
  mongoose.model('Author').findOne({ '<YOUR_AUTHOR_QUERY_OBJ>' }, (err, author) => {
    if(!author) {
      ... create your author
    }
    bookModel.author = author._id
    next();
  })
});
```

This way your schema will take care of this nuance and your code would not have to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

you can extract data of all authors and loop through them to find whether the user exists or not, and making boolean variable to turn it to true if he exists, and depending on that variable value, you can create a new user or not:

```
Author.find({}, function(err, allAuthors){
   if(err) {
  console.log(err);
} else {
  let userFound = false;
  allAuthors.forEach(function(author){
   if(author.name === args.authorName){
   userFound = true
}
});
  if(userFound == false ) {
     let newUser = new Author ({
         name: args.authorName,
         age: args.age
     });
     let books = new book({
         name: args.name, 
         genre: args.genre,
         authorName: args.authorName
     });

} else {
    let books = new book({
         name: args.name, 
         genre: args.genre,
         authorName: args.authorName
     });
}
}
})
```